# Talking to a FTDI (D2XX) device from a Raspberrypi AZero

Tags: usb, serial, pi-zero

I am making a project that uses a Raspberry pi zero (RPi-zero) being controlled by a PC through the UART login (USB TTL cable SSH access, like explained [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable)), and I have used and enabled the USB Ethernet login too ([as described here](http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=791)).

My task: I need to talk to the RPi-zero from a mail PC through the UART serial login, and read a sensor network. This network communicates to RPi through Serial USB connected to the RPi USB. The network is a D2xx device, available from FTDI. I have the drivers in place for the communication (installed as explained on FTDI's site).

Problem: After all the setup, my device isnt recognised on my RPi. I have verified and the device is recognized on my PC and talks through realterm. I have tried using the PyUSB and the FTD2xx library in python to access, but to no avail. The "lsusb" command shows one USB bus available, and the "lsmod" command does not show the ftdi or d2xx modules running. What can I try to debug this?

Comment: Presuming stock Raspbian is still using it (I think it is; if not look into `journalctl`) have a look at `sudo tail /var/log/syslog` before and after you plug in the USB cable.  If you don't see anything...